# Deleting duplicates with group by and count

Tags: mysql, duplication

What is the fastest method to convert the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM tbl_fields
WHERE fieldnotes IS NULL
GROUP BY fieldno,fieldserial,id,fielddate,fieldsid 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

... into one that will *delete* duplicated records? The table does not have any primary keys and contains several million entries.

Comment: Is there a field that is at least unique?

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is an `id` field, but once upon a time, someone merged similar tables, so there's no guarantee they are unique any more (a quick spot check proves this).

Comment: is it possible to add a column to the table and fill the column with a unique key then drop the column after the clean up?

Comment: @Lumpy, if it helps to solve the problem then definitely (but to clarify, nothing currently exists that is unique).

Answer (score 3):

According to your query, you have `fieldno,fieldserial,id,fielddate,fieldsid` as a rule for uniqueness in the `GROUP BY` clause.

You can try this :

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_fields_unique LIKE tbl_fields;
ALTER TABLE tbl_fields_unique
ADD UNIQUE KEY unq (fieldno,fieldserial,id,fielddate,fieldsid);
INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_fields_unique
SELECT * FROM tbl_fields;
ALTER TABLE tbl_fields RENAME tbl_fields_old;
ALTER TABLE tbl_fields_unique RENAME tbl_fields;
```

This will filter rows with duplicate `fieldno,fieldserial,id,fielddate,fieldsid` fields. Look over the new table. Once you are satisfied with the contents of the `tbl_fields_unique` table, do this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_fields RENAME tbl_fields_old;
ALTER TABLE tbl_fields_unique RENAME tbl_fields;
```

### Give it a Try !!!

Comment: It seems to have worked and very quickly at that. However, using a `sum` on the `count` field in my query above, I get 3847, whereas your suggestion finds 5500 duplicates. I'll check the results and get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add an ID column and fill it with a unique value for each record then you should be able to run a query like

```
DELETE FROM tbl_fields
WHERE <New ID Column> IN (SELECT MAX(<New ID Column>)
                            FROM tbl_fields
                           WHERE fieldnotes IS NULL 
                          GROUP BY fieldno,fieldserial,id,fielddate,fieldsid  
                         HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

This would remove the duplicates then you could delete the

If you have enough duplication that you exceed SQLs limitation for the IN statment then You could insert the ID values for the IN statement into a temp table and run an exists against that.

Comment: I added a new column using `alter table tbl_fields add unq mediumint not null auto_increment key` and left your suggestion running for ~3 hours before killing it. Even with a subset of the table it appeared to hang. Is this to be expected?

Comment: This won't work as MySQL does not allow to use the tables that is being deleted in a sub-select.

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE friends_copy LIKE friends;

insert into friends_copy(name,dob)
select name,dob from friends group by name,dob having count(*)>=1
```

Comment: deleting duplicates and keeping only one copy

Comment: insert into friends_copy(name,dob) select name,dob from friends group by name,dob having count(*)=1;

Comment: if only unique records are to be kept

Comment: Welcome to Database Administrators! Please explain how your query solves the author's problem; answers without explanation generally aren't received well.

Comment: A `CREATE TABLE xyz AS SELECT my_fields FROM abc;` is a. better way to go. See fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=745e286d298a059a8377f10f7b8635ff).